# linq2db provider for Postgre SQL 10

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq2db

I want to use linq2db with Postgre SQL 10, but I can't see any Postgre SQL provider of this version.

I found out providers for such versions:

```
public enum PostgreSQLVersion
{
  v92,
  v93,
  v95,
}
```

Also, I have run example app with the latest versions of linq2db library, looked at the `_dataProviders` internal variable of the DataConnection object and ... there are no applicable providers for Postgre SQL of 10 version.

How is this possible? We already have Postgre SQL of 11 version and linq2db have providers only for 9 version? Looks like I have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This enum defines what sql support level linq2db should use during query generation. If you think postgresql 10/11 has some improvements in this area we can untilize - just create new feature request and we will implement it.

Comment: Can't remember new query rules in 10/11 PG. Thanks for answering. This enum a little bit confusing!)

I have already checked it - my PG of 10 version works great with linq2db. Thanks!